# PHP file path not working

Tags: php, css, file, path

I'm using [this](https://reraise.eu/2015/02/19/css-dateien-mit-php-zusammenfuehren-und-komprimieren) php script to combine and minify my css, but it only works for files in the same directory. When I try to link a file with a file path it does not appear in the file. For example:

```
$cssFiles = array(
'files/cto_layout/css/styles.css'
,'icons.min.css'
,'customize.css'
,'animate.css'
);
```

would not add the styles.css content to the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file reveal?

Comment: Why don't you use something like Gulp?

Comment: I agree with the suggestion of using Gulp. But also try using absolute file paths.

Comment: use the absolute path instead relative paths like your example

Comment: Using an absolute path does not solve the problem.

Comment: What is your project directory structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cssFiles = array(
    'files/cto_layout/css/styles.css'
    ,'icons.min.css'
    ,'customize.css'
    ,'animate.css'
);
```

Here, this code says that `styles.css` is in `files/cto_layout/css/styles.css` folder from your current folder. That means if you current folder is `MyProject/assets` that this will look for the file in `MyProject/assets/files/cto_layout/css/styles.css`. I mean the relative path of your current folder. So, I am suggesting you to try using absolute path. for example: use `/files/cto_layout/css/styles.css` instead of `files/cto_layout/css/styles.css`. This `/` will told your PHP to consider the `files` folder in root.

Besides, change the `file_get_contents` implementation with `file_get_contents($filePath, true)` to allow this method for filepath.

Comment: This does not seem to help. It still does not find the file: 'PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/files/cto_layout/css/styles.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ..../contao-3.5.12/files/cto_layout/css/css_1.php on line 34'.

Comment: is your file in `../contao-3.5.12/files/cto_layout/css/css_1.php` here or somewhere else?

Comment: file is under `/contao-3.5.12/files/cto_layout/css/styles.css`, where `contao-3.5.12` the root directory is.

Comment: You see what the error is being said? Your file name is `styles.css` but the php is looking for `css_1.php`. I think you are mixing up the file name. Please recheck.

Comment: Might it be that the problem is that further down the script `file_get_contents` gets used? this is the line the error it thrown, and if I understand the Description correctly it uses only the file name.. What can I do to use the path?

Comment: yes, you can do so by passing an extra parameter on the function. For example `file_get_contents($filePath, true)`